# Iterating through object with a user-defined sort order

Tags: javascript, object

```
var myobject = [
        "A" : {
            color: "red",
            ordering: "3",
              },
        "B" : {
            color: "green",
            ordering: "1",
              },
        "C" : {
            color: "green",
            ordering: "2",
              }
     ];
```

Imagine I have an multi-dimensional object such as the above. If I use a for-in loop to iterate through this object, I'll probably get them in the order A,B,C (but this can't be guaranteed). But what if I wanted to process them in the order given by the 'ordering' property? ie so that they were returned in the order B,C,A. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript (jquery solutions are fine too).

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort, also, you have a syntax error, each item in your array needs to be wrapped in curly braces `{}` e.g `[{
        "A" : {
            color: "red",
            ordering: "3",
              }}, ...`

Comment: You want to first get them into an array and then you can use obj.sort()

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but what you have posted is definitely not a valid JavaScript object, nor is it a valid array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, you need to make sure your JSON is syntactically correct. Objects use braces (`{`, `}`), not brackets (`[`, `]`).
2. Next, you need to convert your object to tuples, so that you can sort them.
3. Finally, you define the sorting function. The one provided works only for nominal cases, so you will have to add your own logic to handle off-nominal and unexpected cases.

### Code

```js
var myobject = {
  "A" : {
    color : "red",
    ordering : "3",
  },
  "B" : {
    color : "green",
    ordering : "1",
  },
  "C" : {
    color : "green",
    ordering : "2",
  }
};

// Convert object to array of tuples.
function objToTuples(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
   return [key, obj[key]]; 
  });
}

// Sorting function to sort tuples by ordering.
function sortByOrdering(a, b) {
  var o1 = a[1]['ordering'];
  var o2 = b[1]['ordering'];
  
  return o1 > o2 ? 1 : o2 > o1 ? -1 : 0;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objToTuples(myobject).sort(sortByOrdering), null, '  '));
```

### Output

```
[
  [
    "B",
    {
      "color": "green",
      "ordering": "1"
    }
  ],
  [
    "C",
    {
      "color": "green",
      "ordering": "2"
    }
  ],
  [
    "A",
    {
      "color": "red",
      "ordering": "3"
    }
  ]
]
```